# how can I get a list of all files and urls on a webpage

Tags: php, url, curl, wget

I'm trying to get a list of all files and urls on a webpage. It's something like the list given on http://tools.pingdom.com when you type in some url. Now I'm trying to do this in php by using cURL or wget. Does anyone has a suggestion about how I can get this kind of file/path lists?

Comment: Continue developing your codes using cURL, to avoid most security blocks when harvesting those content. You are actually building a sort of "google-bot", good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url="http://wwww.xyz.com";
$data=file_get_contents($url);
$data = strip_tags($data,"<a>");
$d = preg_split("/<\/a>/",$data);
foreach ( $d as $k=>$string ){
    if( strpos($string, "<a href=") !== FALSE ){
        $string = preg_replace("/.*<a\s+href=\"/sm","",$u);
        $stringu = preg_replace("/\".*/","",$string);
        $url = $string
    }
}
```

edit:

or you can use this function:

```
function getAllUrls($string)
{
    $regex = '/https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+/i';
    preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
    return ($matches[0]);
}

$url_array = getAllUrls($string);
print_r($url_array);
```

Comment: This will surely get blocked when harvesting pages from protected domains. Avoid using `file_get_content`, `fopen`, `file`. Usually a cURL implementation is allowed.

Comment: @Dexter Huinda, actually I'm trying to get the file list by using  wget -p $url on some url. But I find that wget only get the index.html from most websites. Do you have any suggestion how I can improve my wget codes? I tried wget -p with user-agent and randomly wait settings, but they did not work.

Comment: the $url must be an absolute path to the site

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the document in a string use regex to find all the URLs.

[Match URLs with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442405/regex-to-match-all-valid-links)

[Use regex with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)